# Anet A6 Just finished the assembly, has power but wont turn on

Tags: troubleshooting, electronics, anet-a6

I finished assembly of the Anet A6. The green light on the power box comes on with the fuse removed, turns off when it is put back in place. When checking it with a voltage meter it looks like power is getting to all of the pieces it just wont turn on.

Before I start buying replacement parts I thought I would see if anyone had some suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't wire up the board backwards (with the wrong polarity)?

Comment: What fuse? Add pictures please.

Comment: There might be short circuit in the board. Try checking of powerlines are shorted.